# How to use QOS (quality of service) on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth, qos

i have 15 computers on LAN and other clients who connect through wifi. all connections pass through a windows 7 computer. i want to give high priority for some applications, urls, ip addresses using QOS.

is it possible to control the flow of bandwidth by implementing QOS policies since all the bandwidth passes through one windows 7 computer?

thanks